# Machine Learning Procedure for Fractional/Proportional Data?

Tags: machine-learning, nonparametric, prediction, proportion

I am looking for some suggestions of machine learning procedures that work to predict fraction outcomes where the outcome variables $\in [0,1]$.  Can you provide me with any suggestions?  I thought about using gradient boosting, but I believe this only works on binary data 0 or 1.  I believe there are non-linearities in my data, so I'd like to use something similar to GBM that will take into account non-linear relationships.

I've been looking and still can't seems to find a machine learning procedure for this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you have? The fraction a in $10/100$ or only the value 0.1? Answers will differ, first case is much more informative! Please tell us more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has yet to have a satisfactory answer so I will throw my hat in the ring.

In the case where the outcome represents a fraction of successes from a finite set of trials then a logistic regression as user stan has mentioned seems like a good approach.  In the case where the outcome is a real number between 0 and 1 (not including 0 or 1) then we can use most regression techniques *if* we simply take the logit of the outcome.

The constraint on the outcome to be on the unit interval can be difficult to enforce for many off the shelf algorithms.  However transforming the outcome into a space where the outocme is unconstrained *and then fitting a model in that space* can yield some useful results.  Back transforming the predictions from the unconstrained space to the constrained space will force
the predictions to respect the boundaries.  Let me provide an example.

I'll generate some data which are constrained to be between 0 and 1 exclusive.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.kernel_approximation import RBFSampler
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from scipy.special import expit, logit
from scipy.stats import beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = abs(np.random.normal(0, 2, size = 1000)).reshape(-1, 1)
eta = np.exp(-x/2)*np.sin(np.pi*x)
mu = expit(eta)
kappa = 200
y = beta(mu*kappa, (1-mu)*kappa).rvs()
```

Sklearn in particular has a useful transformer for transforming targets to some space and then back transforming come prediction time.  This is implemented with the `TransformedTargetRegressor` class.  Here is one way to write such a model, complete with some additional features to add non-linearity

```
model = make_pipeline(RBFSampler(n_components=10, gamma=0.05), 
                     TransformedTargetRegressor(LinearRegression(), func=logit, inverse_func=expit))
model.fit(x,y)
```

When I call `.fit`, sklearn will transform `y` via the `logit` function (which takes an outcome on (0, 1) and maps it to the real line) and then train a linear regression model on that transformed data.  Now, when I call `.predict` sklearn will take the predictions from the linear regression and apply the `expit` function (which takes a real input and maps it to the unit interval).  The result is a model which is forced to predict inside the unit interval, as I demonstrate here

[image]

Ignore the ill fit for a moment and notice how the red line (the prediction) flattens at $y=1$ without me telling it to or forcing it to.  This is due to the `expit` transform in the pipeline.

There is no need to use sklearn for this in particular, that library just makes things easy.  The general workflow without the pipelines, feature engineering and transformers may look like...

```
# Transform the outcome first
logit_y = logit(y)

# Now, train a model
fit = LinearRegression().fit(x, logit_y)

# Predict on new data
xx = np.linspace(0, 10, 101).reshape(-1, 1)
predicted_logit_y = fit.predict(xx)

# Map the predictions back to the constrained space
predicted_y = expit(predicted_logit_y)

plt.plot(xx, predicted_y)
```

Code:

````
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.kernel_approximation import RBFSampler
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from scipy.special import expit, logit
from scipy.stats import beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = abs(np.random.normal(0, 2, size = 1000)).reshape(-1, 1)
eta = np.exp(-x/2)*np.sin(np.pi*x)
mu = expit(eta)
kappa = 200
y = beta(mu*kappa, (1-mu)*kappa).rvs()

plt.scatter(x, y)

model = make_pipeline(RBFSampler(n_components=10, gamma=0.05), 
                     TransformedTargetRegressor(LinearRegression(), func=logit, inverse_func=expit))
model.fit(x,y)

xx = np.linspace(0, 10, 101).reshape(-1, 1)
plt.plot(xx, model.predict(xx), color='red')
```
````

Answer (score 0):

If the outcome variable really is a fraction, e.g. 15/200, then the most obvious possibility is logistic regression. Here is an example with R

```
x<-seq(20,80,len=5)
n<-c(50,50,50,50,50)
y<-c(6,10,20,37,44)
frac<-y/n
plot(x,frac,type='o')
fit<-glm(frac~x,family=binomial,weight=n)
```

If the outcome is not really a fraction but just a number between 0 and 1, ordinary linear regression comes to mind. Maybe these don't strike you as "machine learning" techniques, but ML people do use them.

Comment: How would you describe the difference between a fraction like 15/200 and a number between 0 and 1?

Comment: @Dave - with the fraction, you have "successes" and "totals", so to speak, and the "totals" allow you to infer the accuracy of the ratio, e.g., 1/10 is a much less accurate estimate of the true fraction than 10/100.  Your estimation procedure can take into account the different accuracies of the observed fractions based on data that isn't visible if you only have the number.

Comment: @jbowman Do you mean that your data frame would be set up to have predictor variables in a row and 1/10 or 10/100 at the end of that row, or that you have a sample size of 10 in one case and 100 in the other, but the response variable is binary?

Comment: @Dave - some algorithms will take a two-column matrix with columns (Successes, Failures) or some such as the target variable and do the calculations internally, e.g., R's `glm` function with `family = binomial`.

Comment: @jbowman Putting aside software issues, do you mean that the response variable in the regression is binary or can take a value of 1/10?

Comment: @Dave - No, I mean the response variable is a pair (# of successes, # of failures) - or can be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102997/discussion-between-dave-and-jbowman).